# Keyevent on an active textarea(ckeditor) in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the code below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  //function showChar(){
    shortcut.add("Ctrl+F1", function() 
      document.activeElement.id.value +="text";
  });
  var counter=0;
    setInterval(function() {
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
                newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<div><label style="float:left;"></label></div><pre><textarea name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox"  ><%=rsta2.getString("data")%></textarea></pre>');
                newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
                counter++;
                }
CKEDITOR.replace( 'textbox'+i+'',
                    {
                toolbar :
                    [
                        ['Source'],
                        ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike'],
                    ],
                        height: 300,
                        width: 700
                    });  


    },1000);
 });
</script>
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
  <div id="TextBoxDiv0">
  </div>
  </div>
```

The above code(minus the ckeditor part of the code) adds 4 textareas,depending on which textarea is active when I press `ctrl+f1` `text` is added to that particular textarea.But when I replace textarea with ckeditor the shortcut keys dont work.What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your shortcut function with this:

```
    shortcut.add("Ctrl+F1", function() {
      var $active_textarea = $('textarea:focus');
      var current_value = $active_textarea.val();
      $active_textarea.val(current_value + "text");
    });
```

Comment: can I add color to the text?

Comment: Sure. add $active_textarea.css('color','red'); or any other desired color of your choice.

Comment: thnx again for the help

Comment: it changes the entire text in that textarea.just want the color of text to be changed

Comment: If you do not want the text to be changed, then remove the $active_textarea.val(current_value + "text"); line.

Comment: no.I just want the new text that is added using javascript color to be changed to red instead of the entire text in the textarea  data color to be changed to red.the reason for this I want the  text added using javascript to look different then the textarea data

Comment: Unfortunately there is no easy way to accomplish that. If you really need that you will have to create a custom <div> element and work with that, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Hey,Instead of plain textbox,I used ckeditor,but when I try ctrl+f1 it doesnt work like how it used to work with plain textarea

Comment: Unfortunately I am unfamiliar with the ckeditor, so cannot help you with that. I'd advice separating that into another question.

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the textarea that has focus, you can use

```
 $('textarea:focus').val(paste_text);
```

that should do it.

Comment: You're asking a different question now, and without knowing what CK editor is, we can't help you. If your original question has been answered, you need to accept an answer for this question and then pose a new question regarding your next problem.